# How i can get subdomain from exacttarget.com

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

## Hi, how I can get a subdomain in exacttarget.com,

which is served in salesforce example:
i need to get an subdomain like
mycustomsubdomain.exacttarget.com,

and the other question is what's mean that Error when visiting for example :
subdomain.exacttarget.com

- An error has occurred and has been logged by our system. Thank you.*

I am new in salesforce and searching and I didn't get any tutorial

Answer (score 0):

This is in **APEX**,

```
String link = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
String subDomain = link.substringBefore('.'); 
System.debug(subDomain);
```

Here,

-> URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost() will give you the string 'mycustomsubdomain.exacttarget.com'.

-> substringBefore('.'); will give sub domain 'mycustomsubdomain'.

Comment: what is that i want how to setup a subdomain in exacttarget.com